# Run cmd-line program with user input from Java

Tags: java, shell, variables

```
public class Controller {

public String printResults(Process process) throws IOException {
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
    String line = "";
    String container = "";
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        container = container + line + "\n";
        System.out.println(line);
    }
    return container;
}

public String executeCmd(String firstname,  String lastname) throws IOException {
    
    String command = "./myprogram -n " + firstname + " -s " + lastname;
    Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command, null, new File("/home/user/myprogram/build/"));
    return "Hi, \n" + printResults(p);
}
}
```

This allowes me to run a single command with attributes from a specific directory and get back result.

However, I have a larger program, which asks user for inputs from terminal.

```
user@debian:~/program/build/$./program
...
Enter Value: 5
...
Enter Name: Hanz
...
Enter State: GE

Output..
```

How can I **run that program and enter user input from Java**?

Comment: Building a command as a string -- in _any_ programming language -- is a fast route to serious security problems. The underlying OS interface on UNIX -- `execve` -- uses an array of strings; your code should do the same. Otherwise, you need to worry about whether you have, say, a `firstname` of `$(rm -rf ~)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, rewrite your code to use `ProcessBuilder`; it's pretty much just replacing `exec` with `new ProcessBuilder`.

That's because PB gives you some flexibility that may well come up. For example, you can redirect inputs and outputs to files, for example.

Then, run `start()` on the builder and this gets you a `Process` object. You can use this to get the `OutputStream`, and then you can write your string to that: `p.getOutputStream().write("5\nHanz\GE".getBytes());`

There are a couple of different ways to do the job; Have a look at the APIs of Process and ProcessBuilder, there's lots of interesting stuff in there :)